# HTTP Error - 500.30 Asp.net core app failed to start

Tags: asp.net, iis

Cannot open my application on web using IIS as it is showing this error. In the event viewer it is throwing event **I’d-1007 with source IISAspNetCore Module V2**.  Please help me with this as I am struck here. Thanks in advance.

I checked my app settings.json but there’s nothing unusual
I am using dot net 6.0.406 version and I installed 6.0.15 host version x64.
Everything seems to be fine, but I can’t get over this error.

Comment: The event log entry should contain a detailed message on what was wrong. You might want to add that to the question. Besides, you might also rule out common issues by running a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic error, there are many reasons for this error, check your server error logs, there will be detailed error messages.

Besides, please set the attribute value of hostingModelto OutOfProcess and then start the project again.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see details about 500.30 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.